# Find the shortest path in a graph which must pass certain nodes.

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, directed-graphs

I have a directed weighted graph with `16` vertices. One node (bottom left side) is labeled "S" as the starting point, the objective is to find the shortest path that passes through all the "must pass" nodes. Below is the graph, and the colored vertices are the "must pass" nodes. Do you have any theorems and algorithms that I can use? Im thinking about Dijkstra Algorithm, but my goal is to find the shortest path that includes those must pass nodes.
[image]

Comment: The graph represents the map of the game. and the color nodes represent the jungle (monsters) to be eliminated. I have to find the shortest path that passes through the color nodes. The starting point is node S at the bottom left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve the problem via a combination of two algorithms.  First, compute all-pairs shortest path distances between the seven special nodes ($S$ and the colored nodes) in the original directed graph.  This step yields $7(7-1)=42$ distances.  Now replace all distances to $S$ with $0$, and solve an asymmetric traveling salesman problem in a complete directed graph on the seven nodes, using the distances just obtained.  To recover the desired shortest path in the original graph, replace each arc in the TSP tour (except the arc back to $S$) with a corresponding shortest path in the original graph.

The shortest-path distances are

```
   E  G  J  K  M  N  S 
E    10 14 18  4  3  0 
G 10     4  8 14  7  0 
J 14  4     4 16 11  0 
K 18  8  4    20 15  0 
M  4 14 16 20     7  0 
N  3  7 11 15  7     0 
S 13 14 18 22 17 16
```

An optimal TSP tour (with objective value $39$) is then

```
S M 17 
M E  4 
E N  3 
N G  7 
G J  4 
J K  4 
K S  0
```

Expanding the tour to a shortest path in the original network yields

```
S B 9 
B E 4 
E M 4 
M E 4 
E N 3 
N O 4 
O G 3 
G J 4 
J K 4
```

If you want to avoid repeating  $E$, you can replace $M\to E\to N$ with $M\to N$ at the same cost of $7$.

Comment: The optimal value is 39. but when I sum all the weight in the expanded path, the result is 43. Is it contradicting?

Comment: How did you come up with the optimal tour that start with S-M ?

Comment: Sorry, I had an error when manually expanding the tour back to a path.  Corrected now.  I found the optimal tour by using a TSP solver.

Comment: Can I ask for the link to the TSP solver you used? Thanks.

Comment: I used [SAS](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/v_027/casmopt/casmopt_networksolver_details49.htm). But for this tiny instance you could also just enumerate the $6!=120$ tours that start at $S$.

Comment: This is the code I used.
data LinkSetIn;
   input from $ to $ weight @@;
   datalines;
E E 0.0   E G 10.0   E J 14.0   E K 18.0   E M 4.0   E N 3.0   E S 0.0
G E 10.0   G G 0.0   G J 4.0   G K 8.0   G M 14.0   G N 7.0   G S 0.0
J E 14.0   J G 4.0   J J 0.0   J K 4.0   J M 16.0   J N 3.0   J S 0.0
K E 18.0   K G 8.0   K J 4.0   K K 0.0   K M 20.0   K N 15.0   K S 0.0
M E 4.0   M G 14.0   M J 16.0   M K 20.0   M M 0.0   M N 7.0   M S 0.0
N E 3.0   N G 7.0   N J 11.0   N K 15.0   N M 7.0   N N 0.0   N S 0.0
S E 13.0   S G 14.0   S J 18.0   S K 22.0   S M 17.0   S N 16.0   S S 0.0
;

Comment: proc optmodel;
   set<str,str> EDGES;
   set<str> NODES = union{<i,j> in EDGES} {i,j};
   num weight{EDGES};
   read data LinkSetIn into EDGES=[from to] weight;
   num tsp_order{NODES};
   set<str,str> TOUR;

   solve with NETWORK /
      loglevel  = moderate
      links     = (weight=weight)
      direction = directed
      tsp
      out       = (order=tsp_order tour=TOUR)
   ;

   put TOUR;
   print {<i,j> in TOUR} weight;
   print tsp_order;
   create data NodeSetOut from [node]         tsp_order;
   create data TSPTour    from [from to]=TOUR weight;
quit;

Comment: Using that code, I didn't get the result you provide.

Comment: What result did you get instead?

Comment: S G 14 
G K 8
K J  4 
J  N  3 
N  E 3 
E M 4
M S 0

Comment: Your weight from $J$ to $N$ in the input data should be $11$ instead of $3$.  Also, you can omit the self-links like $(E,E)$, which are ignored anyway.

Comment: ow i see. thank you. I got it now.